# How to correctly convert a function into a single-expression function to match a numeric value and string resource?

Tags: kotlin

I am trying to convert several lines of code into a single-expression function in Kotlin. I am passing an Int value that would be used to match and return a single string resource. For example, if value is equal to 3, str would be equal to the resource string element third. Hence, the function numToString would return the string value named "third_sentece". These strings are located in the strings.xml file.

This is the piece of code to improve:

```
fun numToString(value: Int, res: Resources): String {
    val str = when(value) {
        1 -> res.getString(R.string.first_sentece)
        2 -> res.getString(R.string.second_sentece)
        3 -> res.getString(R.string.third_sentece)
        4 -> res.getString(R.string.fourth_sentece)
        else -> res.getString(R.string.fifth_sentece)
    }
    return str
}
```

This is what I have tried. It is incomplete as (R.string....) is missing the string name from string.xml. Which should be set based on the Int value previously passed.

```
fun numToString(value: Int, res: Resources) = res.getString(value, res.getString(R.string))
```

Comment: What is `R`? How `getString` function of `Resources` class work?
If you need to simply convert `Int` into known at compile-time `String` why not just define a respectful mapping?
`val numToStringMap = mapOf(1 to "first", 2 to "second", 3 to "third", 4 to "fourth"); val numToStringDefaultValue = "fifth"`
Then your one-liner will be:
`fun numToString(value: Int) = numToStringMap.getOrDefault(value, numToStringDefaultValue)`

Comment: R refers to the class that contains all the definitions for all resources of a particular application.
Class Resources is for accessing an application's resources. The idea is to retrieve the string resource with name "first", "second"... based on the value passed as parameter. I thought on mapping first, but it's a requirement that I get the strings from the app's resources. In this case they are in the strings.xml. It is possible to do mapping with resources at the same time?

Comment: ok, then you need to map `Int` to resource name and then get resource by its name:
`val numToStringMap = mapOf(1 to R.string.first, 2 to R.string.second, 3 to R.string.third, 4 to R.string.fourth); val numToStringDefaultValue = R.string.fifth; fun numToString(value: Int, res: Resources) = res.getString(numToStringMap.getOrDefault(value, numToStringDefaultValue))`

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Mapping it's a great solution. However, it would still require several lines of code besides the single-expression function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are solutions in Kotlin, but they will most likely include a mapping at some point, either in the form of a `Map` or a `when` statement.

However, in this specific case it looks like you should be looking into [Android plural strings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#Plurals) instead. I haven't done Android development in a while, but if what you're trying to do is associate a different text based on a numeric value, this is most likely the way to go.

```kotlin
fun numToString(value: Int, res: Resources): String =
    res.getQuantityString(R.plurals.numbers_plural, value, value)
```

Another option is to use a [resource String array](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StringArray), and index it by subtracting one to your `value` to accommodate for 0-based indices (`first` is at position 0, `second` at position 1, etc.):

```kotlin
fun numToString(value: Int, res: Resources): String {
    val numberStrings = res.getStringArray(R.array.numbers_array)
    return numberStrings[value - 1]
}
```

If you don't want to use these, then the best option IMO is to extract the common parts from the `when` statement:

```kotlin
fun numToString(value: Int, res: Resources): String {
    val key = when(value) {
        1 -> R.string.first
        2 -> R.string.second
        3 -> R.string.third
        4 -> R.string.fourth
        else -> R.string.fifth
    }
    return res.getString(key)
}
```

If you really want a single expression function here, you can create 2 functions for clarity:

```kotlin
fun numToString(value: Int, res: Resources): String = res.getString(getResourceKey(value))

fun getResourceKey(value: Int): String = when(value) {
    1 -> R.string.first
    2 -> R.string.second
    3 -> R.string.third
    4 -> R.string.fourth
    else -> R.string.fifth
}
```

Comment: In your last example, the first function, would it work if instead of res.getString(getResourceKey(value)) we had it equal to when(value) {1->R.string.first 2->.......}?

Comment: I tested it out and it works. Thanks for your helpful comments  and examples

Comment: @stcol I don't get it. Did you just replace the first function's body with the second function's body? Why? You still need to resolve the key right?

Comment: Hi @Joffrey, since I was trying to make it a single-expression function, I combined both functions: fun numToString(value: Int, res: Resources): String = when(value) {1 -> res.getString(R.string.first).....}. In this way, I would set the result from the when block to the function call

Comment: @stcol yes that works, but that's not what you had written in your comment, that's why I was confused. I usually try to avoid duplication in `when` statements, though. That's why I would tend to prefer extracting the selection of the key into a second method. I did not understand that your goal was "just" this :) but you may still want to look into the other facilities for related resources (plurals/arrays).

Comment: Sorry about that Joffrey, I realized that comment wasn't really helpful. Thanks for following up and giving even more ideas.